# Wired internet connection not detected after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on Acer travelMate 4060, with Ubuntu cd. I have no wired connection. Any help will be appreciated.

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:9f:d0:20:c4  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 Base address:0x2000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:ce:1f:63:e7  
          inet addr:192.168.1.107  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::213:ceff:fe1f:63e7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3845 errors:6 dropped:6 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3646 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2025536 (2.0 MB)  TX bytes:604176 (604.1 KB)
          Interrupt:17 Base address:0xe000 Memory:b0101000-b0101fff 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:794 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:794 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:83138 (83.1 KB)  TX bytes:83138 (83.1 KB)
```

```
     $ dmesg |grep -e eth0 -e 8139
        [    0.220818] pci 0000:06:08.0: [10ec:8139] type 0 class 0x000200
        [   17.559627] 8139too: 8139too Fast Ethernet driver 0.9.28
        [   17.559692] 8139too 0000:06:08.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 16 (level, low) -> IRQ 16
        [   17.560984] 8139too 0000:06:08.0: eth0: RealTek RTL8139 at 0x2000, 00:c0:9f:d0:20:c4, IRQ 16
        [   20.354277] 8139too 0000:06:08.0: eth0: link down
        [   20.354781] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
        [   20.360468] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

`rfkill list all` gives:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no 
Hard blocked: no
```

I have tried `sudo modprobe 8139too` with no results.

Comment: It could be that your ethernet driver is either not installed or not loaded.

Comment: Check your router, check your configuration, check your drivers, check your hardware, and after you've put some amount of effort into attempting to solve the problem, come back here and post relevant information. As it stands there is no way to tell what the problem could be based on the information you've posted here.

Comment: What is the output of `rfkill list all`?

Comment: Looks like we might need `dmesg | grep -e eth -e 8139` as well.

Comment: Hi Seth, rfkill list all gives: rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Answer (score 1):

Please connect the ethernet and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo modprobe 8139too
```

If your connection comes to life, let's get the driver to load automatically on boot:

```
sudo -i
echo 8139too  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

After you load the driver, is an interface created, ideally eth0?

```
ifconfig
```

Are there any clues in the message logs?

```
dmesg | grep -e eth0 -e 8139
```

Let's do some additional tests. Please open a terminal and run:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces  > ethernet.txt
cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf  >>  ethernet.txt
dmesg | grep eth0  >>  ethernet.txt
nm-tool  >>  ethernet.txt
```

Find the file *ethernet.txt* in your user directory and copy and paste it here: http://paste.ubuntu.com. Give us the link in your reply.

I notice your /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf file contains:

```
no-auto-default=00:C0:9F:D0:20:C4,
```

According to the manpage: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man5/NetworkManager.conf.5.html

> List a device in this option to  inhibit  creating  the  default 
>   connection  for  the            device.

Let's do two things to correct this. First:

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Remove the line I referenced above. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Second, click the Network Manager icon and select 'Edit Connections.' Select the Wired Connection and click 'Edit.' Select the General tab and check the box for 'Automatically connect when available...' Save and close. Now does it connect?

Comment: Hi Chili555, I have tried sudo modprobe 8139too with no results could it be wireless driver: description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection taking over the priority???? Thanks for any help

Comment: Network Manager is supposed to give priority to the more secure ethernet. Please see my edit in a few moments.

Comment: ifconfig eth0. ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:9f:d0:20:c4  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 Base address:0x2000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:ce:1f:63:e7  
          inet addr:192.168.1.107  Bcast:192.168.1.255 Askubuntu wouldn't let me post more of results. sure i'm not familiar with postin

Comment: ifconfig eth0. ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:c0:9f:d0:20:c4  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:16 Base address:0x2000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:13:ce:1f:63:e7  
          inet addr:192.168.1.107  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.25

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Please find the ethernet.txt file is in: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8953301/

Comment: Hi Chili555, Thanks so far for your help! I have followed up your latest:sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and removed the no-auto-default=00:C0:9F:D0:20:C4. Edit Connection in network Manager, selected connect Automatically, restarted laptop but still not have Wired connection.

Comment: Please help me to resolve the above problem Thanks

Comment: Hi Chili555, sorry for the delay.Because some of the commands didn't allow me. I had to reinstall Ubuntu 12.04.Now I followed your instructions and resubmitted the results.Still no wired connection. When i tried lsmod i saw: 8139too 23283 0  
8139cp 26718  0 Is it a conflict with these two drivers? Thanks again for your help George

Comment: I doubt it. Can you run the diagnostics I requested above once more? http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Hi Chili555, With my limits I managed this time. the diagnostic results: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9406427/ and for the networkManager.conf http://paste.ubuntu.com/9406510/ Last thing trying networkmanager no connection yet. oNCE MORE THANKS FOR THE HELP!!

Comment: I think the conflict is insignificant. May I also see, after a fresh reboot: dmesg > dmesg.txt  http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Hi Chili555 here are the results of dmesg.txt you request it:http://paste.ubuntu.com/9428234/ Thenk you for your suport George

Comment: Hi Chili555, I just wonder if you have received your request for the dmesg.txt, that I have placed above.Thanks George

Comment: @GEORGE I did, but I regret I see nothing whatever that's suspicious or fixable. I have no suggestions. Sorry.

Comment: Hi Chili555, I wonder if the port for the ethernet cable is defective and is it a way to check it out.I like to thank you so far for your help!! George